# How to forcefully call the drag event right after the creation of an dom element in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I am trying (and failing) to figure out how to call the drag event after the creation of an element. For instance, when I click on a node in my program it creates an edge that should follow around the mouse until the drag end event is called. Unfortunately, when I create the edge the drag event isn't called even though it's been assigned. I don't have any of the code with me at the moment but I can provide some example code of what I am trying to do.

```
<script>     
var bezierLine = d3.line()
   .x(function (d) {
        return d[0];
    })
    .y(function (d) {
        return d[1];
    })
    .curve(d3.curveBasis);

var onClick = function() {

    var t = () => {
        console.log("dsadas");
    }

    var line = d3.select(".container").append("svg:path")
        .attr("d", bezierLine([[100, 200], d3.mouse(this)]))
        .attr("stroke", "blue")
        .attr("stroke-width", 3)
        .call(d3.drag().on("drag", t))
    }

    d3.select(".container")
        .on("mousedown", onClick);

});
</script>

<svg class="container" width="500" height="500" style="background: aliceblue">

</svg>
```

So I assign the `"drag"` to the `t` function and when I click on the canvas it creates an edge but the edge isn't calling the drag event.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Here is a JSFiddle link to use: https://jsfiddle.net/hq62zv4h/4/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to trigger the drag handler manually. If you try to use `line.dispatch("mousedown")` there doesn't seem to be a way to create an event that the handler can use.
Your best bet is to just handle the drag yourself,

```js
var bezierLine = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return d[0];
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return d[1];
  })
  .curve(d3.curveBasis);
var container = d3.select(".container");

var onClick = function() {
  var drag = d3.drag();
  var line = d3.select(".container").append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", bezierLine([
      [100, 200], d3.mouse(this)
    ]))
    .attr("stroke", "blue")
    .attr("stroke-width", 3);

  var move = () => {
    line.attr("d", bezierLine([
      [100, 200], d3.mouse(this)
    ]));
  };
  line.call(drag.on("drag", move));

  container.on("mousemove.temp", move)
    .on("mouseup.temp", () => container.on(".temp", null));
};

container.on("mousedown", onClick);
```

```css
.container {
  background: aliceblue
}

.dragThing {
  fill: lightblue, stroke: black, stroke-width: 2
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.2/d3.js"></script>
<svg class="container" width=800 height=640>

</svg>
```